# SQL DataTable Update?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm not sure, but I think I may have taken a wrong path here.  I am trying to update my customer table on my SQL Server.  I Connected with a SQLDatareader and then loaded that into my Datatable.  I have made all the changes I wanted and now I can't figure out how to get the changes back up.  I thought that the "myDataTable.AcceptChanges();" would trigger that to happen but it doesn't.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
                SqlCommand myCommand;
                DataTable myDataTable;
                SqlDataReader myReader;


                myCommand = new SqlCommand();
                myCommand.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM customer";
                myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
                myCommand.Connection.Open();

                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                myDataTable = new DataTable();
                myDataTable.Load(myReader);

                // Make Data changes here

                myDataTable.AcceptChanges();
                MyDataTable.Dispose();
                MyCommand.Dispose();
                MyConnection.Dispose();
```

Comment: Are you updating one row, multiple rows, all rows? Have you considered issuing a single `UPDATE` command instead of pulling all rows and all columns down to the client to perform a data modification from there?

Comment: Updateing all rows approx 5000

Comment: @StephanM is where is the UPDATE Statement in your code..? looks like you're only doing a Select.. correct me if I am wrong or not seeing something here.. is there a reason why you are not using SQLCommand and SQLConnection to update the database using Parameterized Query..? just wondering..

Comment: AS I said I thought that the .AcceptChanges() would filter that back to the Database.

Comment: Ok I can see your Select Command but in order to update you need another command.. lets start over here question, do you see data when you load the datatable..? from there what mechanism do you use when updating..? are you calling a ButtonClick event..? please explain so you don't get a load of answers from others whom share the same confusion.. does this make sense..

Comment: also calling this myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection); closes the underlying DataReader and or viceversa do you really need that line? why can't you just call myReader.Close();

Comment: The best way to update your SQL data is to send an `UPDATE` command to the server instead of doing it through your application, as @AaronBertrand mentioned above

Comment: All of this code is in the buttonClick. As I said I was able to get data into myDataTable and perform the manipulations I needed to do.  Was able to connect the Datatable to a grid to review that my changes to myDataTable were good.  As to that myReader line of code I found that in an example and things seem to work to this point.

Comment: @StephanM there is a simpler and better way to deal with database transactions by using the System.Data.SqlClient namesace. it is easier to cotrol the acions and use stored procedures with parameters, making sql transactions, getting data from the database as well as updating data stored in the DB

Comment: StephanM you're trying to update things the way one would have done in legacy coding there is a much simpler way of addressing your issue .. I personally would not recommend using DataSets or DataTables for updating and Database when you can do this easier `using System.Data.SqlClient namesace`

Comment: I invited ya to a chat room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a TableAdapter to commit your changes back to the database. Check out this link for details.

[TableAdapter.Update()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm not using a TableAdapter Does that mean I need to rewrite?

Comment: There are no SQL Insert or Update statements.  I updated myDataTable and now want to see those changes in the database as persisted data.

Comment: How do you plan to do that without an update statement in your case..?

Answer (score 0):

In such case you need to use a DataAdapter which has an Update property that takes your Update Query Command.

Even you can use Command Builder and then get the UpdateCommand from CommandBuilder.

***Sample Code from MSDN***

```
SqlDataAdapter catDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories", nwindConn);       

catDA.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Categories SET CategoryName = @CategoryName " +
                                     "WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID" , nwindConn);

catDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@CategoryName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15, "CategoryName");

SqlParameter workParm = catDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int);
workParm.SourceColumn = "CategoryID";
workParm.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

DataSet catDS = new DataSet();
catDA.Fill(catDS, "Categories");   

DataRow cRow = catDS.Tables["Categories"].Rows[0];
cRow["CategoryName"] = "New Category";

catDA.Update(catDS);
```

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)